# ASP.Net WebForms Chrome Blank Page

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, webforms

I've been having a lot of problems with Chrome and ASP.Net WebForms C#. Everything works in IE and FireFox.. I have an Intranet app to manage large data. The post has a lot of data. When I submit the form in Chrome, the the site comes back as a complete blank page. I can't set break points either on the page_load... Has anyone experienced this problem????

Comment: If you open up Chrome Developer Tools, is there anything in the console of note?

Comment: Yes. It appears that the POST data contains 90,000 characters of data. Script Manager, ViewState and form data. I've tried disabling ViewState on that individual page.

Comment: A large POSTbody won't cause any problems in itself. Are you sure you're POSTing to the correct URI? What webserver are you using for testing?

Comment: This is ran on localhost using Visual Studio 2012. It happens on other developer's localhosts as well. Yes, this is going to the correct URI b/c it works fine in FireFox and IE. Just craps out in Chrome.

Comment: Run something like Fiddler or Chrome's Network panel and see if there is anything of note there.